# How to select CaseComment with all comments under it

Tags: case, feedcomment

When you add a CaseComment it shows in Feeds section on salesforce UI

[image]

[image]

You can comment under a CaseComment . I can't select CaseComment(this is a CaseComment 1) with all comments under it(CaseComment comment 1.1).

following query gives me all CaseFeeds with FeedComments but I can't find a way to select CaseComment with all comments(or FeedComments) under it.

```
Select (Select Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, 
               CommentBody, IsDeleted, InsertedById, CommentType, RelatedRecordId 
        From FeedComments) 
From CaseFeed c 
Where c.ParentId = 'something'
```

Comment: query result http://oi39.tinypic.com/2ag20ef.jpg